# Measure execution efficiency for compairing two solutions?

Tags: c++, string, append, move

I want to measure the efficiency for two solutions for the same problem.

I don't need to include any environmental "noise" into the calculation, just I want to know which of these below solutions would perform better in a perfect world, ie.: which needs more steps to execute?

```
string a;
int b;
string c;

//SOLUTION A
c = a;
c = std::move(c) + ',' + std:to_string(b);

//SOLUTION B
c = a;
c.append(",").append(std::to_string(b));
```

I don't really have any experience in measuring execution times in this small scale, so I might have lost in the jungle, sorry if this is the case here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way is to benchmark both solutions, e.g. with [QuickBench](https://www.quick-bench.com/q/slx5XmlWPl4SPArNFU7bgMBVGAI). In the chart:
[image: benchmark results]
you can see that second solution is faster. However, execution time of your code might also be dependent on the size and the number of the strings you try to concatenate, so take it into account. I would also recommend benchmarking whole solution (whatever you try to achieve), not just one line of your code (here: append vs operator+).

You can also try it with different compilers and different optimization levels.

Comment: Agreed on all recommendations. My intention here was to just know which one-liner is better and your answer covers this 100%. Thank you!